# Python LevelDB (plyvel) - Storing image bytes and a dictionary in the same key

Tags: python, leveldb

I have a LevelDB which stores image bytes. I want to save a dictionary containing metadata information about the image in the same LevelDB under the same key.
So far it's working for me but i wanted to ask if there is anything that could go wrong with this method and if there are better ways to achieve this ?

Thanks.

```
#dictionary
metadata = {'width': str(width), 'height': str(height),
                    'size': str(size), 'format': str(fmt),
                    'event_id': str(event_id)}
# storing the key-value
sub_db.put(key, img_msg.data+'.metadict.'+json.dumps(metadata))
# extracting the image-dict
a, b = value.split('.metadict.')
s3.store_fo(key, StringIO.StringIO(a))
s3.modify_metadata(key, json.loads(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

A Safer alternative i decided to use :

```
sub_db.put(key, img_msg.data)
sub_db.put(key+'metadict', json.dumps(metadata))

metadict = json.loads(sub_db.get(key+'metadict'))
```